# Set images in imageView array?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I ran into an issue that I'm not sure how to go about solving. I have a `Cell` object where I create some `IBOutlets` that I want to display inside my `UITableView` to my screen like so:

```
class EventCell: UITableViewCell, CellDelegate{   
    @IBOutlet var eventName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var eventLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var attendeesImages: [UIImageView]!
}
```

I also have another function where I try to set the cell contents of that cell like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Dequeue a "reusable" cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(eventCellIdentifier) as! EventCell
    setCellContents(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

//Set contents of Event Cell.. self.events is a global array
//which have information that EventCell objects need to display

func setCellContents(cell:EventCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
    let item = self.events[indexPath.section]
    var count = 0

    cell.eventName.text = item.eventName()
    cell.eventLocation.text = item.eventLocation()

    //Attempt to set the cell.attendeesImage values
    for value in item.attendeesImages() {
        cell.attendeesImages[count].image = value
        cell.attendeesImages[count].clipsToBounds = true
        cell.attendeesImages[count].layer.cornerRadius = cell.attendeesImage[count].frame.size.width / 2
        count++
    }
}
```

The issue is, when I try to set the values of `cell.attendeesImages`, I run into an issue saying `fatal error: Array index out of range`. The issue is because I am accessing an index that doesn't exist in `cell.attendeesImages`. Is there any way to allocate or set the size of `cell.attendeesImages` before I assign its contents? Or is there simply a better way to assign the images within the `cell.attendeesImages`? I also tried to set `cell.attendeesImages` as an array of `UIImage` and setting `cell.attendeesImages = item.attendeesImages`  but if it is as an `UIImage`, I can't seem to display the images onto the screen whereas the `UIImageView` will allow me to do so. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for value in item.attendeesImages() {
    cell.attendeesImages[count].image = value
    cell.attendeesImages[count].clipsToBounds = true
    cell.attendeesImages[count].layer.cornerRadius = cell.attendeesImage[count].frame.size.width / 2
    count++
}
```

With

```
for (count, value) in enumerate(item.attendeesImages()) {

    var workingImage : UIImageView! = nil
    if count >= cell.attendeesImages.count {
        workingImage = UIImageView(image : value)
        cell.addSubview(workingImage)
        cell.attendeesImages.append(workingImage)

        //TODO: Layout image based on count
    } else {
        workingImage = cell.attendeesImages[count]
    }

    workingImage.clipsToBounds = true
    workingImage.layer.cornerRadius = workingImage.frame.size.width / 2
}

//Loop through remaining images from cell-reuse and hide them if they exist
for var index = item.attendeesImages().count; index < cell.attendeesImages.count; ++index {

    cell.attendeesImages[index].image = nil
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. I understand how your answer works but for some reason I am not getting the images to display.. might you have any idea why?

Comment: With the previous method, I was able to get one image to display, but with this method I can't seem to get anything to display.

Comment: Sorry @user1871869 I didn't notice attendeesImages was a collection of IB `UIImageViews`. I've updated my answer to use those existing images and update their image property. I simply added a check to ensure the new image wasn't out of the bounds of the attendeesImages array.

Comment: If your IB UIImageViews aren't being updated, double check your storyboard to make sure they're connected to attendeesImages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for updating your answer! I really appreciate the help. I made sure that my attendeesImages is connected to the storyboard but I am running into an interesting issue. I changed the code to the updated answer (and added the cell.attendeesImage.append(existingImage)) portion but I still get no images displayed. I noticed that when I put a print statement inside the `if count >= cell.attendeesImage.count` statement, this statement never returns true... any ideas why?

Comment: @user1871869 I've updated my answer to ensure your images are added and old reused images are hidden. You'll need to layout the new UIImageViews but otherwise this should take care of your problem. In hindsight, you should really pass an array of UIImages to your cell in a method and have it deal them and lay them out internally... Something like 'func updateWithNewImages(images : Array<UIImage>)` - using the logic posted above.

Comment: Hi, this is awesome. Thanks for this! One quick question: where is `existingImages` coming from? I can't seem to figure out where it should go in the code.

Comment: That was a typo - it's now fixed

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help. I don't seem to be getting the count issue anymore but I noticed one thing: on the first cell, the correct image shows up, but on the second cell, nothing shows up. Also, the image that does appear is much bigger than what I set it to be on the Storyboard and is positioned incorrectly. Furthermore, only one image is being displayed. I printed out the count inside `if count >= cell.attendeesImage.count` and found that that portion of code is only being called once when I should have two images displayed.  Any ideas for why this might happen? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83090/discussion-between-thattyson-and-user1871869).